# vimscript - reliable way of checking win and buf type of a new window with autocommands

Tags: vim, autocommand

So, I faced a need to check a type of a window and a buffer when entering a new window so I can do some stuff automatically depending on the types of aforementioned stuff.

For example, when `quickfix` is opened, I need to know that it is it, the same with `command` window, `help`, etc. Putting it in other words - I need to know when the new window opened is a regular window with a regular buffer in it.

The only ways that I wound was a combination of `win_gettype()` and `&buftype` options.

First thing I tried was an obvious `WinEnter` event, which didn't work properly as I couldn't check the type of a buffer.

Then, I tried `BufEnter`, but that wouldn't catch `:split` without arguments, apparently in a way similar to `BufWinEnter`. In addition, that wouldn't catch `quickfix` when it is opened for the first time and `command`.

So, coming to the **question** - is there any reliable way to validate window's and buffer's type *automatically* when a new window is opened without taking into account the way it was opened in? To summarize - there are two problems - 1) cannot catch a window at all if it is opened with `:split` without arguments, 2) cannot catch types reliably (see Edit 2).

**EDIT 4**

Well, with **EDIT 3** taken into account, `WinEnter` works properly and as expected. But this is still a huge workaround. Will leave the question open in case anybody has an adequate solution.

**EDIT 3**

Well, I cannot see how to check things from **EDIT 2** below upon window or buf entrance, but I guess it is possible to check them once again afterwords. I've come up with an idea to catch `terminal` with `TerminalOpen`, check `command` once again with `CmdWinEnter`, and  fix`quickfix` problem with checking its' `filetype` with, well, `FileType`. These are huge workarounds, but I cannot see another way of solving this yet. Unfortunatelly, `:split` problem is still a thing.

**EDIT 2**

I've elaborated a bit on the main question and played a bit more with all this stuff. It seems like `command line` is caught. But terminal behavior is weird. So, behavior of different windows with `WinEnter` and `BufEnter` is as follows:

```
|Window    |WinEnter|BufEnter|
|:---------|:-------|:-------|
|quickfix  |   -    |+, 2    |
|command   |   -    |    +   |
|help      |   -    |    +   |  
|terminal  | +, 1   |+, 1    |
```

1 - but only if another terminal window is opened (the first one is not being caught);

2 - but fails for the first time after Vim startup.

*Sorry for the table, it forces me to indent it for some reason, and it breaks all the pretty visuals on the page.*

**EDIT 1**

Adding a snippet of code. The whole idea of what I am trying to do is storing an information about all the windows currently opened that are regular windows with regular buffers. Each time new window is opened or an old window is closed I need this info to be updated automatically. The core code is below:

```
function HandleNewWindow()
    let winid = win_getid()
    let wi = getwininfo(winid)[0]
    let bufnr = wi.bufnr

    if !CorrectBufAndWinTypes(bufnr, winid)
        return 1
    else
        " add winid to the list of regular windows' IDs
    endif
endfunction

function CorrectBufAndWinTypes(bufnr, winid)
    let wt = win_gettype(a:winid)
    let bt = getbufvar(a:bufnr, "&buftype")
    let wi = getwininfo(a:winid)[0]
    let is_terminal = wi.terminal
    let is_quickfix = wi.quickfix

    echom "WT - " wt "BT - " bt is_terminal is_quickfix

    if wt !=? "" || bt !=? "" || is_terminal || is_quickfix
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    endif
endfunction

" I was trying to handle it with the autocommands below:

" autocmd BufEnter * call HandleNewWindow()
"     cannot detect quickfix window at first try
"   (subsequent tries are positive, though)
"     can detect help, but only via &buftype

" autocmd WimEnter * call HandleNewWindow()
"     cannot detect quickfix at all
"     cannot detect help at all

"     both cannot handle command window (q:)
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to deal with buffers and thus use `:help 'buftype'`.

`:help win_gettype()` tells you if a window is:

- a popup window
- a preview window
- a command-line window

`:help getwininfo()` tells you if a window is:

- a quickfix window
- a terminal window

Having those related informations split between two inconsistently named functions is as ugly as can be but well…

Comment: This language is indeed killing me. Thank you for your advise, but it solves only a half of my problem - I still have all other issues (though replacing `&buftype` is for sure a good thing).

Comment: By the way, you, kind Sir, seem to be a pundit of the sacred ways of Vim-fu. Could you advise if there is any way to check buf type by its number?

Comment: You don't have the other issues because you don't have to wonder about the buffer anymore and thus you only need `WinEnter`.

Comment: As for your second question: see `:help getbufvar()`.

Comment: As for `WinEnter` - it seems like right after this event Vim knows about the id of the window but doesn't know anything about it's type, as it cannot determine the window is a `quickfix` in a autocommand fired on the event. `BufEnter`, as I wrote in the question, seems to be catching it, but only at the second and subsequent attempts.

Comment: It would help to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in answer. Please find the updated info in the question text.

Comment: Do you really need that information in real time, e.g. "I want to play a sound whenever a normal window is created"/"I want the number of normal windows displayed in the status line"?

Comment: I don't know how weird that sounds, but kinda yes, in the most real time possible.

Comment: I guess I can catch `command line` buffer by its name, but I still cannot see how to do it timely.

Comment: Yes, it sounds weird, especially given the lack of explicit justification. The only reason to want real time, here, would be if you wanted to have a side-effect happen in real time too. If you don't, then there is no need for real time and you can simply query the current state _when needed_.

Comment: Side-effect description is accurate. In general, every time the window is opened I need to display a certain info related to it, given the window is a regular window with a regular buffer.

Comment: Tested it a bit more and added the new info into a post, if you would find it interesting to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out `:h :buffers` which shows all buffers.

`:buffers[!] [flags]` where `[flags]` restricts the buffers to be listed. For example

```
" Show all active buffers
buffers! a

" Show regular active buffers
buffers a

" Show special(unlisted) active buffers
buffers au
```

You can also `:filter` buffers by displayed buffer name

```
filter /\.vim/ buffers a
```

Another way to get all buffers is `getbufinfo()` which provides more details.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for spending time on this question! Though this is a good point, I cannot yet see how this answers my question or how I can apply it to solve the problem.

Comment: I mean, I can see the buffers that are unmodifaible to catch `quickfix`, `help` and `terminal`,  but the open question is still when exactly to do it to catch the type timely and in a reliable fashion.

Comment: Tested it a bit more and added the new info into a post, if you would find it interesting to find out what is happening.

Comment: There are a number of events on buf change. I see you mentioned `BufEnter, WinEnter`. I'm not sure, maybe a combination of them and `BufWinEnter` as well as `BufNew, BufAdd` can cover most cases.

Comment: `BufWinEnter` doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately. But, you got me thinking in a way of using some other events to catch the rebellious windows and buffers after `BufEnter` and co somehow, and I come up with the idea to catch `terminal` with `TerminalOpen`, check `command` once again with `CmdWinEnter`, and  fix`quickfix` problem with checking its' `filetype` with, well, `FileType`. These are huge workarounds, but I cannot se another way of solving this yet. Unfortunatelly, `:split` problem is still a thing.

Comment: Ok, with the above taken into account, `WinEnter` seem to work fine with `:split`. I guess the problem is solved.